# Kendo UI Grid passed data to another form

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this [demo that relate with my situation](https://dojo.telerik.com/uHEKOZiH), how to bind an additional data in `dataSource` into my popup form. A popup form will appear if `outletType = rest`. Appreciate your helps.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/uHEKOZiH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set *additional data*, all dataSource's data will be available to be used in the modal, you don't need to show them in the grid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<style>
  #additionalVariables #lbl{width: 150px; display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 15px;
</style>
  
<div id="grid"></div>  
  
<div id="additionalVariables" style="display:none">
  <label id="lbl" for="capacity">Capacity</label>: 
  <input type="text" class="k-textbox" name="capacity" id="capacity" data-bind="value: selected.capacity" style="width:120px; text-align:center;"> 
  <br>
  <label id="lbl" for="roomservice">Room Service</label>:
  <input class="k-radio" type="radio" name="roomservice" id="yes2" value="y" checked="checked"/> 
  <label class="k-radio-label" for="yes2" >Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="k-radio" type="radio" name="roomservice" id="no2" value="n" /> 
  <label class="k-radio-label" for="no2" >No</label>
  <br>
  <label id="lbl" for="fastfood">Fast Food</label>:
  <input class="k-radio" type="radio" name="fastfood" id="yes3" value="y" checked="checked"/> 
  <label class="k-radio-label" for="yes3" >Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="k-radio" type="radio" name="fastfood" id="no3" value="n" /> 
  <label class="k-radio-label" for="no3" >No</label>
</div>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  
  
  var dataSource = [{
  'capacity': '',
  'roomservice': 'y',
  'fastfood': 'y',
  'outletType': 'retail',
  'name': 'Data 1',
    'additionalData': {
      'a': 1
    }
 },
 {
  'capacity': 888,
  'roomservice': 'n',
  'fastfood': 'n',
  'outletType': 'rest',
  'name': 'Data 2',
    'additionalData': {
      'a': 2
    }
 },
 {
  'capacity': '',
  'roomservice': 'y',
  'fastfood': 'y',
  'outletType': 'theme',
  'name': 'Data 3',
    'additionalData': {
      'a': 3
    }
 },
 {
  'capacity': '1232',
  'roomservice': 'y',
  'fastfood': 'y',
  'outletType': 'rest',
  'name': 'Data 4',
    'additionalData': {
      'a': 4
    }
 },
];

  grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
    columns: [
      { field: "outletType", title: "Outlet Type", width: 150, editor: outletType,
       template: data => data.outletType == "rest" ? "Rest" : (data.outletType == "retail") ? "Retail" : (data.outletType == "spa") ? "Spa" : "Theme" },

      { field: "name", title: "name", width: 75 },

      { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
    ],
    edit: openOutType
  });
});    
  
 
function openOutType(e){
    if(e.model.outletType == 'rest'){
      console.log(e.model.additionalData);
      
      var additionalForm = $("#additionalVariables");
      additionalForm.kendoWindow({
        visible: false,  
        modal: true,   
        width: "350px",
        height: "200px",
        iframe: false,
        resizable: false, 
        title: "Addtional Information" 
      });
   additionalForm.data("kendoWindow").center().open(); 
    }
}
  
  
function outletType(container, options) { 
  $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio1" name="outletType" type="radio" value="rest" >').appendTo(container);
  $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio1">Rest&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>').appendTo(container); 

  $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio2" name="outletType" type="radio" value="spa" >').appendTo(container);
  $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio2">Spa&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>').appendTo(container);

  $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio3" name="outletType" type="radio" value="retail" >').appendTo(container);
  $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio3">Retail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>').appendTo(container);

  $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio4" name="outletType" type="radio" value="theme" >').appendTo(container);
  $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio4">Theme</label>').appendTo(container);
  
  
  $('input:radio[name="outletType"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'rest'){

      var additionalForm = $("#additionalVariables");
      additionalForm.kendoWindow({
        visible: false,  
        modal: true,   
        width: "350px",
        height: "200px",
        iframe: false,
        resizable: false, 
        title: "Addtional Information" 
      });
   additionalForm.data("kendoWindow").center().open(); 
    }
  });

}

   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Updated Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uHEKOZiH/2)

Comment: understand that, as long have data in dataSource, it can be call by the model. Thanks for your help

Comment: Need your help here. I update the [demo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/uHEKOZiH/3). Situation when the is grid load, I click on `Edit` button in `Data 2`. As you can see it load data model correctly, then I close the `kendoWindow` and cancel for update. Then I realize I need to update `Data 3`, and click on `Edit` button again and choose option for `Rest`, then popup window appear but in here data model in `radiobutton` not same with the dataSource. Any idea how to fixed this problem?